# Unknown name of this test

Tags: error

I would like to know the exact name of a test for measuring the similarity of 2 noise systems.

Assuming m1 being the measurement for system 1 and m2 the measurement for system 2 this test computes S1 = (m1 + m2)/2 and S2 = (m1 - m2)/2.
Then it plots S1 vs S2 for each measurement point.

Thanks a lot

ps no one of the 2 systems is the ground truth

Comment: if anyone knows other tests that give an indication of how good two systems measure the same thing is welcome of course...

Comment: You're trying to compare two measurements of the same system to assess reliability or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing a Bland-Altman plot. It plots the average of the two methods, (m1+m2)/2, vs their difference m1-m2. The Bland-Altmant plot is used for assessing agreement between two methods.

Comment: Ah, a Tukey mean-difference plot :)